# MySQL error after deleting a row (Error 1194)

Tags: database, crash, migration, mysql

I am running a MySQL database in windows server 2003. Because it is extremely old, I want to migrate all my data to a new Windows Server 2012 instance. I started dumping all the data into dumps. The problem is that I had to delete a row in a database's table, and I did it manually (note that I did the deletion while no dump was being generated). After that, while trying to query my table, or creating a dump from it I get:

`Table 'table' is marked as crashed and should be repaired` with `ErrorNr.` -> `1194`.

What would be the procedure to "repair" the database. Any advice on this? I am also worried that I will lose any data. I wanted to make a table/database dump before trying to repair it, but while doing so I get the same error.

Any suggestions? Does anybody know how can I backup my database?

Thank you for your advice in advance!

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html for details.

```
REPAIR TABLE mytable;
```

Comment: do you know what is the likelihood of my table to become useless? how secure is to "repair" a table? would I lose data?

Comment: It's impossible to tell. From my experience it works pretty well but of course as the table was damaged there will be some loss.